# Why is Scala code to replace substring in a file slow?

Tags: performance, scala, sbt

I am using the following to replace substring in a file:

```
def mapFile(file: scala.reflect.io.File, replace: String => String) {
  file.printlnAll(file.lines.toList map replace: _*)
}
```

and for replace I pass the following function: `_.replaceAllLiterally("${finalName}", "some-str")`

Actually this happens as a part of sbt script, and even for small files (several short lines) it takes about 8 seconds for each text file.

What is the bottleneck here? How can performance be improved?

**UPD**. You can find *build.sbt* here: http://pastebin.com/8BiqpdWc

Comment: what are the benefits of scala.reflect.io.File over java.io.File or java.nio.file.Files ?

Comment: none... it's just used in logic surrounding this piece. I can easily get to java class if it helps

Comment: ok :) consider also whether `lines` needs be cast to a list before mapping. Possibly `toList` for a whole file is an expensive operation that can be bypassed.

Comment: I consider this... Though I'm not sure how I can get rid of this cast. Also files are very small currently (3 lines or smth).

Comment: Huh. Implemented it on my end, replacing words in a 40 line file. Only taking 0.0022 seconds. Are you sure this is your actual bottleneck? Seems odd that a 3-line file would take any noticeable amount of time.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the project in GitHub to play with?

Comment: Jacek, I am a little bit ashamed to do this, because I'm putting too much into build.sbt  (had to go with Build.scala). But just for the purpose I can get some more help please see this build.sbt over here: http://pastebin.com/8BiqpdWc

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this plugin: http://software.clapper.org/sbt-editsource/
can be of a help to solve my issue (substitute `${key}` occurrences in source files and then put results to target-folder).

Performance is cool. I just had to re-compile that plugin from sources for SBT 0.13 (the latest supported version targeted SBT 0.12). See [here](https://github.com/bmc/sbt-editsource/issues/6)

Anyway I'm still interested why simple replacements are slow in my case.